# how to download file from azure storage blob in project repository inside build pipeline (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure-devops

Need a way to download a set of files from Azure Blob storage to Project repository during the build.

The aim of process is to CI-CD the mobile app. but the mobile app's icon, background image and some other images are provided by other application, so during build the images are suppose to take from blob storage container.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Azure Powershell to do that, would probably be the easiest way of doing that:

```
$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name yyy
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context

# download blob
Get-AzStorageblobcontent -Blob "Image001.jpg" `
  -Container $containerName `
  -Destination "D:\_TestImages\Downloads\" `
  -Context $ctx
```

Reading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#download-blobs

Comment: How can this work without first authorizing the Agent somehow so it can access the blob? How can this be done? When I try something like this, all I get is `Get-AzStorageAccount : No subscription found in the context.  Please ensure that the credentials you provided are authorized to access an Azure subscription, then run Connect-AzAccount to login.`

Comment: well, you cant unless the blobs are publicly accessible. if they are - raise a new question and post a link, I'll provide you the answer how I was doing that